# Get LastWriteTime of a particular file

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise 1709 and PowerShell ISE v5. I am trying to get the last write time to the file deployment.properties by checking to see if the testpath holds the file and if it does, write the LastWriteTime of that file. I'm not sure I'm doing this the correct way. Any help showing me how to make this work would be appreciated. I've tried several options but this is the only one that doesn't produce an error. However, the code runs, completes without error but doesn't produce and output. My code is listed below first and then the output I see on the PowerShell ISE screen.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass

$env:COMPUTERNAME = HostName

$DeplPath = "AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"

$dateTime = foreach ($User in Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory) {
    $folderFile = Join-Path $javauser.FullName $DeplPath
    if (Test-Path $folderFile) {
        $testResult = Get-ChildItem  | select -Property fullName, LastWriteTime 
        } Else {
        $testResult = "Not found - deployment.properties"
        }
}
$dateTime
```

Below is the output I get which returns no information.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass

$env:COMPUTERNAME = HostName

$DeplPath = "AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"

$dateTime = foreach ($User in Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory) {
    $filelist = Join-Path $User.FullName $file
    if (Test-Path $filelist) {
        $testResult = Get-ChildItem $dateTime | select -Property fullName, LastWriteTime 
        } Else {
        $testResult = "Not found - deployment.properties"
        }
}
$dateTime


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Newly modified code below

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass

$env:COMPUTERNAME = HostName

$DeplPath = "AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"

$dateTime = foreach ($User in Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory) {
    $folderFile = Join-Path $User.FullName $DeplPath
    if (Test-Path $folderFile) {
       $testResult = Get-ChildItem  | select -Property fullName, $DeplPath.LastWriteTime 
        } Else {
        $testResult = "Not found - deployment.properties"
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Computer Name" = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        "Java User True/False"       = $TestResult
        "Users"         = $user.Name
        "Last Write Time" = $testResult.LastWriteTime
    }
}
$dateTime
```

Comment: It looks like you're running a different version of the script than you pasted. This line: `$folderFile = Join-Path $javauser.FullName $DeplPath` should read `$folderFile = Join-Path $User.FullName $DeplPath`.

Comment: @RichMoss yes, thanks for the catch. However, I still get the same result -no error and -no output.

Comment: Maybe you meant to output `$testResult` instead of `$dateTime`?

Comment: The variable `$dateTime` would gather ***all*** output generated in the foreach, but there is not a single command which outputs something, so the var ***has to be*** empty.

Comment: @LotPings Thank you for the assistance. That totally escaped me. As you are aware, I'm trying to modify what you helped me with the other day. I'm adding the new code just below the last. This works but doesn't get the LastWriteTime. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. Your property select for the get-childitem were mislabeled.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass

$env:COMPUTERNAME = HostName

$DeplPath = "AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"

$dateTime = foreach ($User in Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory) {
    $folderFile = Join-Path $User.FullName $DeplPath
$test = Test-Path $folderFile
if ($test -eq $True)  {
       $testResult = Get-ChildItem $folderfile | select -Property Name, LastWriteTime 
        } Else {
        $testResult = "Not found - deployment.properties"
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Computer Name" = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        "Java User True/False"       = $TestResult
        "Users"         = $user.Name
        "Last Write Time" = $testResult.LastWriteTime
    }
}
$dateTime
```

Comment: Thank you. This does exactly what I needed and I'm learning much.